# Promisify node tls.connect method

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

What would be correct way of promisifying `tls.connect` method in a way that it should resolve with a `socket` instance on successful connect.I found it a little bit tricky because as it seems there is no way out of the box to distinguish between error while connecting and regular error during communication with TCP server (after successful connect). Although it looks somewhat smelly it could be something like

```
const connect = (port, host, options) => {
  /**
   * Some workaround to be able
   * to distinguish between error on connection
   * and error after connection was established successfully
   */
  let connected = false

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const socket = tls.connect(port, host, options, () => {
      connected = true
      return resolve(socket)
    })

    socket.on('data', (data) => {...})
    socket.on('end', () => {...})
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {...})
    socket.on('error', (err) => {
       if (!connected) {
         return reject(err)
       }
       console.error(err)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the socket immediately and add a `connected` promise to the socket instead - that way you can attach the other handlers synchronously and still listen to connection with a promise:

```
const connect = (port, host, options) => {
  let resolve, reject;
  var connected = new Promise((res, rej) => { resolve = res; reject = rej; });
  const socket = tls.connect(port, host, options, resolve);
  socket.connected = connected;
  socket.on('error', reject); // it's fine to calll reject/resolve several times
  return socket;
};
```

Comment: how does this exactly works? What im up to is to connect for one single time when app is about to start, and to reuse same socket after initial connection. Lets say that app start and connect resolve with an socket object. In your example what will happen after lets say 2 hours or something when there is an error while reading/writing to the socket, what will happen when this line is invoked `socket.on('error', reject)`

Comment: Absolutely nothing, the promise is just for the connection and not the content.